# How do I return from a void method

Tags: java, eclipse, void

I have a problem where the comment in the code is, and it is as follows:
My code is trying to pull 7 random cards from My `getFullCollection()` method,
however, it does not allow Me to return any value because it states that void methods can not return a value. The code:

```
public class Packs {
    Deck classicSet = new Deck() {
    public void getFullCollection() {
    classicSet.getFullCollection();
    Random PO = new Random();
    int number;
    for(int counter = 1; counter<=7;  counter++) {
        number = 1+PO.nextInt(10000000);
        if(number < 41650) {
            return packag.Cards.Rarity.Common; //the problem
        }
```

it says:

> Void methods cannot return a value

```
public void getFullCollection() throws IOException{
            Cards Shuriken = new Attacks(3, 2, packag.Cards.Effects.Return, packag.Cards.Class.Ninja, packag.Cards.Rarity.Common, ImageIO.read(new File("Shuriken.png")));
            System.out.println(Shuriken.toString());
            this.cards.add(Shuriken);
```

I tried deleting the void return type on my `getFullCollection()` class and replacing it with `public int getFullCollection()`, but it does not work

```
    class Attacks extends Cards {   
    private int damage;
    private int Mana;
    private final Effects effects;
    private BufferedImage card;
    private final Rarity rarity;
    private final Class class1;
    Attacks(int damage, int Mana, final Effects effects, final Class class1, final Rarity rarity, BufferedImage card) {
    super(Mana, effects, rarity, class1, card);
        this.damage = damage;
        this.rarity = rarity;
        this.class1 = class1;
        this.effects = effects;
        this.Mana = Mana;           
        this.card = card;
    }
```

This method is how I make cards in the `getFullCollection` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you creating a special form of deck with overwriting the getFullCollection() method?

Could u provide a simple description what the first code snippet should do, so i can unserstand better?

and if you do that you cant use a return

i am assuming this for loop is there to determine wich Rarity your cards schould be, so you would maybe have to source that out to another method if you want to use your return that way

Comment: yes, sorry about that, so i have created 3 main classes, 1st, the attacks extends cards which sets how a card should look, 2nd the getFullCollection class in which i use the parameters i set in the 1st class to create cards, and the 3rd in which i declare i want to use only the cards from getFullCollection (i intend to add more expansions), generate a random number, and return a card based on what number the player rolls

Comment: so in this getFullCollection method, you want to return a List of Cards ?

Comment: So you can eighter make your mehthod return a List<Card> or you try to handle all that stuff inside the method without return

Answer (score 1):

As [@MartinScheuchenpflug pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62655249/833070), I cannot use a return statement here. Below is the code on how to dance around that return statement:

```
if (number < 10000001) {
    Random cards = new Random();
    int i1 = cards.nextInt(7);
    if(i1 == 0) {
        pack_cards.add(packag.Deck.Shuriken);
```